# Smoke does not show in Post-render (neither Cycles nor Evee) (Blender 2.81)

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

Please be informed that:
I have  reset the settings to factory default. 
It does render in real time on both EVEE and Cycles but not in Post render. 
Please Help out if you can think of anything it doesnt matter if you arent sure, just tell me caUSE I have been stuck for 2 days, and tried a lot of things, I need someone who can think out of the box, maybe the solution is very simple, and yes I did try reinstalling the app. 
Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't baked the simulation.

1. Save the .blend file.
2. Open the *Physics Properties* and click *Bake* in *Smoke > Cache*.

[image: Bake]